# Where are site permissions in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Firefox sometimes asks for permission to open links with other programs. Examples:

[image: Allow this site to open magnet links with Transmission]

[image: Allow this site to open video links with IINA]

After checking *Always allow…*, where can I find a list of all these site permissions to manage them?

Thank you!

Comment: On which Operating System?

Answer (score 2):

#### Where can I find a list of all these site permissions?

I don't think there is a place that lists all permissions.

> If you have granted any special permissions to a website, you will see a  PermissionsIcon [image]in the address bar.
>
> This will open the the Permissions panel, where you can view and
> adjust permissions for the website:
>
> [image]
>
> You can click the X next to any permission entry to clear the status.
> This will restore the default setting for that type of permission.

Source: https://assets-prod.sumo.prod.webservices.mozgcp.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2021-05-10-05-10-41-059f8e.png

Answer (score 1):

Site permissions are listed in
[Firefox Page Info window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-page-info-window?as=u&utm_source=inproduct&redirectslug=Page+Info+window&redirectlocale=en-US#Permissions).

Here are three methods for reaching it :

- If the Menu bar is enabled, click Tools and select "Page Info"
  from the drop-down menu and go to the Permissions tab
- Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
  and go to the Permissions tab
- Click the padlock
  [image]
  to the left of a web page's address, then click "Connection secure",
  then "More information", and go to the Permissions tab